# How to dynamically declare a array present inside a structure using malloc

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I currently have the following code in my program:

```
struct mystruct
{
    int x;
    struct y *list[10];
}

mystruct *h1=(mystruct *)malloc(sizeof(mystruct));
```

I want to declare the array `list` dynamically (using `malloc()`) when I declare the structure. Could anyone tell me how to go about this?

Comment: Might I suggest a #define or const for the list size.  You'll thank me later when you need to change it...

Comment: at some point in my program, i have to re-size the array. That is why i cant use a #define or const.

Comment: @hektor then you shouldn't be making it constant in your `struct`. Do `struct y **list`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do it explicitly. I normally do this with a wrapper function like this.

**Edit:** Now there's a complete working example at the bottom.

```
struct mystruct *mystruct_init()
{
    struct mystruct *mystruct = calloc(1, sizeof(*mystruct));

    // loop through and allocate memory for each element in list
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        mystruct->list[i] = calloc(1, sizeof(*(mystruct->list[i])));
    }

    return mystruct;
}
```

That way, you just call this in your code:

```
struct mystruct *h1 = mystruct_init();
```

You'll also want to write a corresponding `mystruct_free()` function.

Here's a working example (for me):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct y {
    int a;
};

struct mystruct {
    int x;
    struct y **list;
    int list_length;
};

struct mystruct *mystruct_init()
{
    struct mystruct *mystruct = calloc(1, sizeof(*mystruct));

    // loop through and allocate memory for each element in list
    mystruct->list_length = 10;
    mystruct->list = calloc(1, sizeof(struct y *) * mystruct->list_length);
    for (int i = 0; i < mystruct->list_length; i++) {
        mystruct->list[i] = calloc(1, sizeof(struct y));
    }

    return mystruct;
}

void mystruct_free(struct mystruct *mystruct)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < mystruct->list_length; i++) {
        free(mystruct->list[i]);
    }

    free(mystruct->list);
    free(mystruct);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct mystruct *h1 = mystruct_init();
    h1->x = 6;
    printf("%d\n", h1->x);
    mystruct_free(h1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How can you reference y ? I suppose that you made a mistake :)

Comment: Just to add to @DanFego's code, be sure to `free()` the memory got from `malloc()` after you are done. There are many threads on Stack Overflow explaining memory leaks caused due to returning a local variable from a function. One link: http://stackoverflow.com/a/423206/630866

Comment: @DanFego: i modified the program according to your suggestion. However i am getting a segmentation fault when the execution hits this line                                                            "  mystruct->list[i] = calloc(1, sizeof(*(mystruct->list[i]));"        what could be going wrong? should i paste my full code?

Comment: @hektor I might have made a mistake with my `sizeof`. Try changing it to `sizeof(struct y)` and see if it works. :)

Comment: @hektor I just quickly mocked up a program with no faults, though I fixed a couple more typos above, including on the line mentioned. Perhaps you corrected it with a parentheses in the wrong place?

Comment: i changed the line to                                         mystruct->list[i] = calloc(1, sizeof(struct y)); Still end up with the segmentation fault :(

Comment: @hektor: updated with my own working example. Perhaps try that?

Comment: @DanFego : Does this match the program you made up              struct mystruct *mystruct_init()
{
    struct mystruct *mystruct = calloc(1, sizeof(*mystruct));

    // loop through and allocate memory for each element in list
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        mystruct->list[i] = calloc(1, sizeof(struct y));
    }

    return mystruct;
}

Comment: @DanFego: Since i have to re-size my array at a later point of time in the program, i have declared list is struct node **list. Will the current implementation hold in this case as well?

Comment: @hektor yes, but you'll need to change your initialization constant (10) and the same one in the free function. So you'll want to store a variable in the `struct` that contains the number of elements in the list so you know how much to free.

Comment: @DanFego: i changed the initialization to struct y **list and use the same wrapper function. It is giving me a segmentation fault at this line hashtable->list[i] = calloc(1, sizeof(*(hashtable->list[i]))); Sorry for disturbing you for so long, but it'd be really nice if you could point out my mistake.

Comment: @DanFego: if i want to increase the size of 'list',how do i use realloc to accomplish that? should i do a realloc on mystruct as well as list? If so, could you tell me how to go about it?

Comment: @hektor At this point you should search SO for this new question, and if you can't find an answer, post a new question for it. :)

Comment: @DanFego: i posted a new question. However i have a doubt with the code that you provided, especially with the parameter '1' in the calloc function. Could you explain that?

Comment: @hektor `calloc()` takes two parameters: the number of blocks to allocate and set to `0`, and the size of each block. So it's grabbing `1` block of the given size, set to `0`.

Answer (score 1):

If you're only going to port to machines (compilers) that support C99, then you could consider using the 'flexible array members', which is the portable version of the 'struct hack'.

> §6.7.2.1 Structure and union specifiers
>
> ¶16 As a special case, the last element of a structure with more than one named member may
>   have an incomplete array type; this is called a *flexible array member*. With two
>   exceptions, the flexible array member is ignored. First, the size of the structure shall be
>   equal to the offset of the last element of an otherwise identical structure that replaces the
>   flexible array member with an array of unspecified length.<sup>106)</sup> Second, when a `.` (or `->`)
>   operator has a left operand that is (a pointer to) a structure with a flexible array member
>   and the right operand names that member, it behaves as if that member were replaced
>   with the longest array (with the same element type) that would not make the structure
>   larger than the object being accessed; the offset of the array shall remain that of the
>   flexible array member, even if this would differ from that of the replacement array. If this
>   array would have no elements, it behaves as if it had one element but the behavior is
>   undefined if any attempt is made to access that element or to generate a pointer one past
>   it.
>
> ¶17 EXAMPLE Assuming that all array members are aligned the same, after the declarations:
>
> ```
> struct s { int n; double d[]; };
> struct ss { int n; double d[1]; };
> ```
>
> the three expressions:
>
> ```
> sizeof (struct s)
> offsetof(struct s, d)
> offsetof(struct ss, d)
> ```
>
> have the same value. The structure struct `s` has a flexible array member `d`.
>
> <sup>106)</sup> The length is unspecified to allow for the fact that implementations may give array members different
>   alignments according to their lengths.

---

In context, that means you might write:

```
typedef struct mystruct
{
    int x;
    struct y *list[];
} mystruct;  // Note that this is necessary; C++ automatically recognizes mystruct; C does not.
```

To allocate space, you might use:

```
mystruct *h1 = (mystruct *)malloc(sizeof(mystruct) + 10 * sizeof(struct y *));
```

This allocates a `mystruct` with enough space for 10 pointers in the array.  You can later resize the memory with:

```
mystruct *new_h1 = (mystruct *)realloc(h1, sizeof(mystruct) + 20 * sizeof(struct y *));
if (new_h1 == 0)
    ...handle out of memory error, but note that h1 is still valid...
h1 = new_h1; // Safe
```

(Note that I carefully do not assign to `h1` on the reallocation; to do so would leak memory if you get a memory allocation failure.)

You can reference them as if the array was there:

```
h1->list[0] = ...;
```

Note that you cannot have an array of `mystruct`, but you can have an array of pointers to `mystruct`.  It is also up you to keep tabs on the size of the array; you'd normally do something like have one of the fixed members record the size allocated.