# segmentation fault when accesing into a structure

Tags: c, parsing, segmentation-fault

When I am executing printf command for level->description, the program gives me segmentation fault. I don't know why. Should I use malloc to repair it? The content (only 1 line ending with '\n') of file sokoban.dat is "chicago;addie;story begins here;-----#####-----------|-----#@$.#-----------|-----#####-----------"

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

typedef struct {
char *name;
char *description;
char *password;
char *map;
struct level *next;
//char *solution;
} LEVEL;

LEVEL* parse_level(char *line) {   //parsing from file into the structure
    LEVEL level;
    char level_name[50];
    char level_password[50];
    char level_description[100];
    char level_map[200];

    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    while (line[i] != ';') {      //getting level name
        level_name[j] = line[i];
        i++;
        j++;
    }
    level_name[j]='\0';
    level.name=&level_name[0];
    //strcpy(&level.name,level_name);
    //printf("%s\n",level.name);
    printf("%s\n",level_name);
    j = 0;
    i++;
    while (line[i] != ';') {     //getting level password
        level_password[j] = line[i];
        i++;
        j++;
    }
    level_password[j]='\0';
    level.password=&level_password[0];
    printf("%s\n",level_password);
    j = 0;
    i++;
    while (line[i] != ';') {     //getting level description
        level_description[j] = line[i];
        i++;
        j++;
    }
    level_description[j]='\0';
    level.description=&level_description[0];
    printf("%s\n",level_description);
    j = 0;
    i++;
    while (line[i] != '\n') {    //getting level map
        level_map[j] = line[i];
        i++;
        j++;
    }
    level_map[j]='\0';          
    level.map=&level_map[0];
    printf("%s\n",level_map);
    j = 0;
    level.next=NULL;    
    LEVEL* levelPointer=&level;
    return levelPointer;
}  
int main(){
    FILE *fp = fopen("sokoban.dat", "r");
    if( fp == NULL ){
        printf("No such file\n");
        return 1;
    }

    char line[500];
    //strcpy(line,"");
    char c;
    int i=0;
    while((c = fgetc(fp)) != '\n'){ //reading from file 1 by 1 character
       line[i]=c;
       i++;
    }
    printf("%s\n",line);
    LEVEL* level;
    level=parse_level(line);
    //printf("%s\n",level->description);   **//!!! this is where error occur**
    printf("%s\n",level->map);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use a debugger such as gdb to find exactly where in your code your problem is, or comment-out portions of your program to narrow down the fault. As it stands, other StackOverflow users are unlikely to work very hard to solve your problem.

Comment: problematic is the 5th row from the bottom (this is when error occurs). I am using NetBeans for debugging and for variable level->description it gives me adress: 0x52 <Address 0x52 out of bounds>.

Comment: OK, so is there a mull terminator in there?

Comment: (1)`printf("%s\n",line);` : `line`  not null-teminated.,

Comment: (2) `while((c = fgetc(fp)) != '\n'){`...`while (line[i] != '\n') { ` `line` not icluded `\n`.

Comment: (3) `return levelPointer;` return local value address.

Comment: Ouh... I think you hit it...'\0' character is not copied from file to `line` variable.

Comment: but changing `'\0'` to `EOF` does not prevent seg fault.
So problem is with returning local variable adress?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct level {
    char *name;
    char *description;
    char *password;
    char *map;
    struct level *next;
    //char *solution;
} LEVEL;

#if 0
char *strdup(const char *str){
    size_t len = strlen(str);
    char *ret = malloc(len + 1);
    if(ret){
        memcpy(ret, str, len + 1);
        //ret[len] = '\0';
    }
    return ret;
}
#endif

LEVEL* parse_level(char *line) {
    //Returns the allocated memory
    LEVEL *level = malloc(sizeof(LEVEL));
    char *token;
    token=strtok(line, ";");//It cut the string as a separator the ';'.
    level->name = strdup(token);//Copy the memory allocated strings cut out.

    token=strtok(NULL, ";");//Get next token
    level->password = strdup(token);
    token=strtok(NULL, ";");
    level->description = strdup(token);
    token=strtok(NULL, ";");
    level->map = strdup(token);
    level->next = NULL;
#if DEBUG
    printf("debug print : level\n");
    printf("%s\n", level->name);
    printf("%s\n", level->password);
    printf("%s\n", level->description);
    printf("%s\n", level->map);
#endif
    return level;
}
void LEVEL_free(LEVEL *p){
    free(p->name);
    free(p->password);
    free(p->description);
    free(p->map);
    free(p);
}

int main(){
    FILE *fp = fopen("sokoban.dat", "r");
    if( fp == NULL ){
        printf("No such file\n");
        return 1;
    }

    char line[500];
    char c;
    int i=0;
    while((c = fgetc(fp)) != '\n'){ //reading from file 1 by 1 character
       line[i]=c;
       i++;
    }
    line[i] = '\0';
    printf("%s\n",line);
    LEVEL* level;
    level=parse_level(line);
    printf("%s\n",level->description);
    printf("%s\n",level->map);

    LEVEL_free(level);//free for malloced memory
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank You very much!.....I can now move on. I didn't know of function `strtok()`
Actually is this necessary?
    `#if 0
    char *strdup(const char *str){
        size_t len = strlen(str);
        char *ret = malloc(len + 1);
        if(ret){
            memcpy(ret, str, len + 1);
            //ret[len] = '\0';
        }
        return ret;
    }
    #endif`

Comment: @Dounchan ; I had wrote exemplary `strdup`  that isn't a standard function. It isn't required if already exists in the your environment (in <string.h>).

Answer (score 1):

In the function, `parse_level()` you take addresses of all the local variables and copy into the `struct` variable `level` and return `level`. All these copy of local addresses and using those objects later *after* their lifetime make your program illegal and causes [undefined behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You should read about basics of language first and understand concepts such as pointers, arrays, returning values from a function, returning pointers etc before diving deeper.

The ones related to your problems are:

[returning a local variable from function in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4824342/returning-a-local-variable-from-function-in-c)

[Since I can't return a local variable, what's the best way to return a string from a C or C++ function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423186/since-i-cant-return-a-local-variable-whats-the-best-way-to-return-a-string-fr)

[Undefined, unspecified and implementation-defined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior)

[Undefined behavior and sequence points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points?rq=1)

[The Definitive C Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: No doubt that I should study more. The best method is learning by examples. I will get through the links provided by you
Anyway, Kernighan & Ritchie book is quite hard to absorb!