# C - Pointer points to random values

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I'm pretty confused by pointers in general and I have no idea why this is happening. Normally a pointer to an array would just print out the values of an array but I have no idea why this is happening. Could someone explain why or suggest what is happening?

```
char *showBits(int dec, char *buf) {
    char array[33];
    buf=array;
    unsigned int mask=1u<<31;
    int count=0;
    while (mask>0) {
        if ((dec & mask) == 0) {
            array[count]='0';
        }
        else {
            array[count]='1';
        }
        count++;
        mask=mask>>1;
    }
    return buf;
    }
```

Expecting it to return a binary representation of dec, but printing it produces  random garbage.

Comment: `val` isn't defined anywhere.

Comment: *Normally a pointer to an array would just print out the values of an array*. No, pointers don't print anything.

Comment: 'return buf;' returns pointer to local array with automatic storage - UB.

Comment: `array` goes out of scope.

Comment: Duplicate of [Function returning address of local variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22288871/function-returning-address-of-local-variable-error-in-c).

Comment: 'char *showBits(int dec, char *buf)' passing in 'buf' is pointless since you overwrite it with 'buf=array;'

Comment: @MartinJames Buf passes in an empty array.

Comment: @lurker Doesn't it normally print out the value stored at the address?

Comment: @danielwestfall it does not matter what it passes in:)  You splat the parameter with your pointer to 'array'.

Comment: @MartinJames splat the parameter?

Comment: @danielwestfall were you attempting to COPY array to the one whose address is passed in as 'buf'?

Comment: @danielwestfall sorry..  Overwrite.  Assign to.  Change the value of.   The point is that the passed-in value of parameter 'buf' is lost when you do 'buf=array;'

Comment: @MartinJames Yes. Is there a better way to store a decimal number as a binary string rather than an array?

Comment: Possible duplicate (can't cv): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423186/since-i-cant-return-a-local-variable-whats-the-best-way-to-return-a-string-fr

Comment: Another time, please ask only one question per Question. While it's not unreasonable to have more than one question, if they are *tightly* related, Questions should usually stick to a single question, not tack an additional thing on at the end.

Comment: @Mayken Ok, that seems completely reasonable. Just curious while I have your attention.

Comment: There seems to be one more problem: You're not null-terminating the string either.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Do I have to manually add the null terminator at the end of the string?

Comment: Maybe helpful: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: @danielwestfall this is C. In C you have 2 choices. You null terminate your strings or you shoot your foot.

Comment: @danielwestfall write full code and debug

Comment: Duplicate - returns pointer to the automatic char array. After return it does not exists anymore

Comment: @danielwestfall, no, pointers do not "print" anything.

Answer (score 1):

You have

```
char *showBits(int dec, char *buf);
```

and the function is expected "*to return a binary representation of dec*".

Assuming `int` is 32 bits, do

```
#define INT_BITS (32) // to avoid all those magic numbers: 32, 32-1, 32+1
```

Assuming further that the function is called like this:

```
int main(void)
{
  int i = 42;  
  char buf[INT_BITS + 1]; // + 1 to be able to store the C-string's '0'-terminator.

  printf("%d = 0b%s\n", i, showBits(i, buf));
}
```

You could change your code as follows:

```
char *showBits(int dec, char *buf) {
  // char array[INT_BITS + 1]; // drop this, not needed as buf provides all we need
  // buf=array; // drop this; see above

  unsigned int mask = (1u << (INT_BITS - 1));
  size_t count = 0; // size_t is typically used to type indexes

  while (mask > 0) {
    if ((dec & mask) == 0) {
      buf[count] = '0'; // operate on the buffer provided by the caller. 
    } else {
      buf[count] = '1'; // operate on the buffer provided by the caller. 
    }

    count++;

    mask >>= 1; // same as: mask = mask >> 1;
  }

  buf[INT_BITS] = '\0'; // '0'-terminate the char-array to make it a C-string.

  return buf;
}
```

Alternatively the function can be used like this:

```
int main(void)
{
  ...

  showBits(i, buf);
  printf("%d = 0b%s\n", i, buf);
}
```

The result printed should look like this in both cases:

```
42 = 0b00000000000000000000000000101010
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're returning a reference to local array. Instead, let the caller allocate the buffer. I've also fixed some other problems in the code:

```
#define MAX_BUFFER_LENGTH (sizeof(unsigned int) * CHAR_BIT + 1)

char *to_bit_string(unsigned int n, char *buf) {
    unsigned int mask = UINT_MAX - (UINT_MAX >> 1);
    char *tmp;

    for (tmp = buf; mask; mask >>= 1, tmp++) {
        *tmp = n & mask ? '1': '0';
    }

    *tmp = 0;
    return buf;
}
```

First of all, we use unsigned int instead of signed int here, because signed ints would be converted to unsigned ints when used in conjunction with unsigned int. Second, unsigned ints can have varying number of bits; so we use `sizeof(unsigned int) * CHAR_BIT + 1` to get the absolute maximum of the number of bits. Third, we use `UINT_MAX - (UINT_MAX >> 1)` as a handy way to get a value that has only the most-significant bit set, no matter how many value bits the number has. Fourth: instead of indices, we use a moving pointer. Fifth - we  remember to null-terminate the string.

Usage:

```
char the_bits[MAX_BUFFER_LENGTH];
puts(to_bit_string(0xDEADBEEF, the_bits));
```

Output

```
11011110101011011011111011101111
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit modified code - the caller should provide buff to accommodate the string

```
char *showBits(unsigned int dec, char *buf) {
    unsigned int mask = 1u << 31;
    int count = 0;
    while (mask>0) {
        if ((dec & mask) == 0) {
            buf[count] = '0';
        }
        else {
            buf[count] = '1';
        }
        count++;
        mask = mask >> 1;
    }
    buf[count] = '\0';
    return buf;
}
```